# Linking CSS file with PHP throgh all folders

Tags: php, html, css

## INTRO

I am new to php. I love that it allows me to change one header.php file and it updates all over the site.

IF all - index.php, header.php, style.css, article.php, homework.php files are in the ROOT folder, everything works like magic, I like it. I use:

```
<?php include_once "header.php"; ?>
```

at the top of index.php, article.php and homework.php and the header appears.

to load css a regular =

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

is enough to have in my header.php file, because all the files are in the same directory.

## MY PROBLEM

When the amount of articles becomes too large and I decide I want to put those articles in different folders, that is when  stuff gets confusing and I would like to know a proper way to solve it.

### New website folder structure

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\articles\homework.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\views\header.php and style.css
C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\articles.php
```

Now please help me how to make homework.php file to load the css from the header.php? I manage to load the header itself with

```
<?php include_once "..\views\header.php";?>
```

BUT the css file doesn't load for some reason.
I read something about "basenames", "site roots", but don't know how to properly set them up.

#### The perfect scenario

The perfect scenario would be if I could have a basename variable that I can change, so when I make my server live I can just change the basename to the appropriate new server directory and because all the header.php and other blog files were linked to that basename, everything would change automatically. I have done too many manual directory rewriting to do it once again, please tell me a way to automate it :)

Thank you a lot!

p.s!!!!!! Before I even post this question I realized that the header.php is trying to load views/style.css, which doesn't make sense, because the style.css file is in the same folder as header.php now.. Somehow basenames, site roots are a must here I believe...

Comment: Use `href="/views/style.css"` instead, `/` at the beginning makes it use the root folder. Edited to reflect the new folder structure

Comment: File system and URL relations are distinct. And `<base href=…>` solves it for the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, brother, this is stupidly simple, but it works. I have been at it for two days now.. and you just told me to use ```/```. Great @brombeer

Comment: @mario could you elaborate a little bit more please? Thank you for your time. How can I implement it in my file structure?

Comment: Just be aware that if you are testing on some servers, particularly XAMPP with localhost / does not work to access root

Comment: @kerry Which servers would that be? And using XAMMP with localhost `/` won't take you to root? I have my doubts. (Might be because of a wrong setup)

Comment: @brombeer - I have never had any success with XAMPP for Windows, standard install, being able to reference the root in html using something like '/CSS/style.css  ../ works fine.  I have tried correcting as advised in a few articles but every fix seems to cause a problem or extra complication elsewhere.  I am happy to be corrected and educated :-)

Comment: @kerry If you have multiple projects and set them up like `http://localhost/project1` and `http://localhost/project2` it won't have the desired effect. If however you use VirtualHosts like `http://project1.local` and `http://project2.local` with their respective DocumentRoots `/` has never failed me. And something like `<a href="/"...` should always take you to the server's root/index page

Comment: @brombeer Brother, watch this video, it helped me to set up multiple local projects wiht XAMPP, hope it will help you out too! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4E7UgKiw34

Comment: @arvygasp What? Why? I don't use XAMPP and I know how to set up VirtualHosts. I _have_ multiple local projects set up.

Comment: @brombeer I just thought you wanted to be "corrected and educated". Apologies. Good for you then!

Comment: @arvygasp No problem. That was kerry, not me ;)

Comment: @ arvygasp @ brombeer sorry if I caused a fight :-)

Comment: @brombeer, I'll try that thanks, sorry for causing confusion with arvygasp but I did have to laugh, did you watch the video, did you learn anything :-)

Comment: @arvygasp, that was me, I'll check out the video thanks.

Comment: @kerry Everything fine here, no fight, all good! ;)

Comment: My bad :o first time using a forum. Good luck you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify relative paths such as ../css - means up one folder then look in css folder or ../../  - means up 2 levels then look in css folder.

../../main/css/style.css - would mean up 2 levels then look in main/css for the file style.css.

The problem with using / or ../ etc is that if you decide to change the location of the resource you still have to change all your paths.  Using a var you can simply change it to reflect the new location.

with PHP you can also getcwd() and dirname() and realpath() to get a string representing a location, you can then set a base variable for your files and 'path' down from it.

This way you can use the same variable to locate a file rather than different relative paths depending on the level of the file calling it.

DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is also useful for avoiding errors between / and \ with linux and windows OS. However I believe Windows and Linux will both resolve /

Personally I like to set path locations to commonly used files such as /includes in config.php then I can use that setting from anywhere

In summary you are just either discovering a path using PHP or setting a path as a variable

```
$path = 'c:/htdocs/mysite/includes/';
```

then using the variable as part of the path name when you access the file

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

can also be useful to identify your site home folder